# Share WCF RIA Services between ASP.NET MVC and Silverlight clients

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, forms-authentication, asp.net-authorization

I want to use WCF RIA Services as the middle tier for multiple clients including Silverlight and ASP.NET MVC.

I created a solution with Domain classes in a separate assembly using WCF RIA Services 4.2 CTP and Database First, which I want to share between the Silverlight and MVC clients. The solution looks like this:

```
Solution Foo
   Foo.RIAServices.Server.Entities
     Foo.RIAServices.Server.Entities
     Foo.RIAServices.Server.Entities.Web
   Foo.RIAServices.Client
   Foo.RIAServices.Client.Web
   FooMvcApplication
   FooMvcApplication.Tests
   FooResources
```

What if anything is wrong with my architecture and approach? Is there a better approach to using the Microsoft Entity Framework to create a common service for multiple clients?

Can I create a common custom Authentication service for both? Will the [EnableClientAccess()] and [RequiresAuthorization] decorations be respected for all clients?

Comment: this is a great question, did you find any answers, how is the project going?